# What is the difference between OSX, Linux and Windows System Authorisation?

Tags: linux, osx, macintosh

Last week my lab instructor started giving us introduction about linux and how to use CLI commands.

Anyway, he started insulting and joking about Mac OSX systems and how they are a joke systems. He said that, he used it for a week in my university department and he faced a problem, "you don't have a fully control on your machine; you always have to sudo to be a superuser -- that's why I use Windows" he said. "Mac is a ***linux*** based, Apple basically modified some codes, and mixed some to make this OS" he said.

I've been a Mac user since a kid, and I have learned that having a root access to do any daily work is a very bad and dangerous practice.

What do you guys think about what he said? did he really misunderstood Unix machines?

I'm not trying to prove or argue with anyone nor him, I just want to know if what he said could possibly be true? or he was just sharing his biased opinion?

**Update:**

***What I meant is, if there is any difference between OSX, Linux and Windows authentication system?***

Comment: 1) sorry but this kind of opinion based question is off topic here 2) OSX is NOT based on Linux but on BSD via NExtSTEP 3) You always have to sudo to be the superuser on all *nix machines, unless you log in as root. Perhaps OSX does not let you do so but I don't know. 4) What is your actual question here? Why your instructor dislikes OSX? How should we know? Maybe he dislikes white keyboards. Are you asking if OSX is a Linux clone? It's not, as I said but if so, please [edit] your question.

Comment: Windows also has some kind of sudo mechanism called [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control).

Comment: @terdon the root account is locked by default, but you can unlock it. that will let you log in graphically and via `su`. and you can _always_ use `sudo -i` or somesuch.

Comment: @terdon If you would like me to delete or close the question, I would do so. My actual question is about doing sudo. I may have used the wrong title. Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify it, there is no question in your post about sudo. What are you asking? If OSX has sudo? What the difference in authentication system between OSX and Linux is? Or between OSX and Windows? Just edit and make your question clear.

Comment: This is the question that I wanted to ask. Thanks @terdon! I edited  my question.

Comment: Mac is not based on Linux, it is based on BSD. Both BSD and Gnu/Linux are a form of Unix. Unix is more secure than MS-Windows. But at the expense of having to authenticate from time to time. You can set up sudo to not ask for a password. But that would make it insecure.

Answer (score 3):

Your friend is very wrong on one important point: one ***never*** has full control over their machine, even when running as the superuser. It is the *processes* running on the machine that have control over it; the user merely interacts with these *processes* in order to direct the computer to perform the desired actions. And if these *processes* happen to include malware, then the malware has control over your machine too.

Comment: Wow! I've never actually thought about that myself! Excellent answer. Thanks.